# Close down the [small-business] here!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

The [small-business](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/small-business) tag seems quite meta, and I don't see how an "expert" in small business would profit from using this tag.

Thoughts? Should we keep it or get rid of it?

Comment: There are 17 questions with this tag.  Half of them are off-topic, anyway, and the [small-business] tag adds nothing relevant on any of them.  This should be an easy [status-planned].

Comment: Removed from all questions except for 
http://superuser.com/q/76256/281154

which is on hold...

Comment: The heck is going on here? It's gone on SO, we have to put up with the tag, and just what? Wait?

Comment: Good, I feel better now :)